# Custom keybinds

Tags: c#, key-bindings

I'm attempting to make custom keybinds from a comboBox. The point is for the end user to be able to select "1" or something, to then be able to press it and make something happen.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string option1;
    string keyhelp;
    keyhelp = "VirtualKeyCode.VK_";
    option1 = keyhelp + comboBox1.Text;
    var function1 = bind.InputDeviceState.IsKeyDown((VirtualKeyCode)Enum.Parse(typeof(VirtualKeyCode), option1));
    
    if (function1)
    {
        if (checkBox1.Checked)
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the NuGet package "input simulator".

Comment: Please re-read the [mre] guidance on posting code and [edit] the question to show just necessary code with all data inline as well as expected/actual behavior with corresponding errors as text inside the post. (Note that data you pass to `Enum.Parse` looks strange - you may want to check what that function takes as arguments before updating the post)